# How to iterate over an object to find out 'periods of time' in which the value is larger than 0?

Tags: javascript

I am building a booking app. I have created an object with times and the number of vacancies for each of these times.

```
{
 1000: 1,
 1030: 4,
 1100: 4,
 1130: 2,
 1200: 0,
 1230: 1,
 1300: 0
 //... 
}
```

Times are separated in 30 minute intervals, but services can take longer than 30 minutes (but are all multiples of 30 themselves). E.g.: `service1.duration = 90`

I now need to build a script that identifies in which periods of time a service can be executed. In the example above, `90/30 = 3`, so I would have to find `3` sequential keys in that object that have a `value > 0`.

There would be two in the example above: `[1000, 1030, 1100]` and `[1030, 1100, 1130]`.

Ideally, the periods would be returned in an array just as the two I have exemplified.

Problem: I don't know how to iterate over both keys and values. I know Object.keys and Object.values can be used, but not how to combine them.

Comment: SO isn't a free code-writing service. Please show what you've tried and where you're hitting difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I've just edited my answer.

Comment: there is an `Object.entries` method. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) together, as they are both guaranteed to be in ascending order for number-like keys.

```js
const times = {
 1000: 1,
 1030: 4,
 1100: 4,
 1130: 2,
 1200: 0,
 1230: 1,
 1300: 0
 //... 
};
const getPeriods = time => {
  const keys = Object.keys(times);
  const values = Object.values(times);
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= values.length - time; i++){
    let works = true;
    for(let j = i; j < i + time && works; j++){
      if(values[j] <= 0){
        works = false;
      }
    }
    if(works){
      res.push(keys.slice(i, i + time));
    }
  }
  return res;
};
console.log(getPeriods(3));
```

Comment: it almost works perfectly. If you try ```const times2 = {
 1000: 1,
 1030: 4,
 1100: 4,
 1130: 2,
 1200: 0,
 1230: 1,
 1300: 0,
 1330: 3,
 1400: 2,
 1430: 2,
 1500: 1,
 1530: 2,
 1600: 2,
 1630: 4,
 1700: 0,
 1730: 3,
 1800: 2,
 1830: 0,
 1900: 1,
 1930: 2,
 2000: 3,
 2030: 2,
 //...
};``` and ```getPeriods(4)``` it won't get the last period, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030.

Comment: it does work now! Thanks. I've been trying to understand your logic now but I think it's too complex for me. Would you let me bother you one last time and ask you how you got to this algorithm?

Comment: @cuomo The code loops over all the indexes up to the index where the number of elements from it to the end is equal to the `times` parameter. Inside the loop, I check all the elements from the current index to the current index plus `times` subtract one to see if there are `times` consecutive keys greater than `0`. If there are, I just slice this portion of the array and add it to the result.